# Extract population count from GeoTIFF based on mask layer

Tags: python, rasterio, rioxarray, geocube

I downloaded [Population Count](https://doi.org/10.7927/H4JW8BX5) data from *Gridded Population of the World (GPW), v4* as a *.GeoTIFF file. In a next step, I would like to extract the population count of a given area based on a mask layer (e.g. the political boundaries of Portugal imported from a *.geojson).

I came across an [answer on StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260380/97137), which I believe is trying to achieve a similar result. However, I could not reproduce it due to `NotImplementedError: multi-dimensional sub-views are not implemented` and I suspect the solution would be *overengineered* for me.

When I open the *.GeoTIFF file in QGIS and display the layer properties, I see the following information (I suppose, I am interested in the `STATISTICS_MEAN`):

[image]

The files are avialble for download here (only for seven days or 100 downloads though):

GeoTIFF: https://send.firefox.com/download/a4be075f0dda3acb/#UlUv5RDx8i3XXvV4dQHtEA
Geojson: https://send.firefox.com/download/54d3458a17ca355a/#DM8M3hGOfcoIDOVeKcMZJA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you can do with geocube and rioxarray.

Here is an example I followed to generate this:
https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html

```py
import geopandas
import numpy
import rioxarray
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

gpd = geopandas.read_file("portugal.geojson")
gpd["mask"] = 1

raster = rioxarray.open_rasterio(
    "gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2020_30_sec_portugal.tif",
    mask_and_scale=True,
)
mask = make_geocube(
    gpd,
    measurements=["mask"],
    like=raster,
    fill=0,
)
```

[image]

Then, to get the total population:

```py
total_population = raster.where(mask.mask).sum().item()
```

```
16079493.21870717
```

EDIT:

Installation method:

```
conda create -n geo geocube
conda activate geo
(geo)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce it yet due to an error with GDAL `CRSError: The EPSG code is unknown.`. The error is described here https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html but I was not able to solve it yet.

Comment: Do you have the environment variable GDAL_DATA set? Also is PROJ_LIB set?

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know what that means.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I believe I just installed it either via `pip install gdal` or `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`.

Comment: Just updated installation method. It should work with conda-forge. If you activate your environment before use, it should set the environment variables for you.

Comment: Thank you for cour continuous support. I deinstalled gdal and reinstalled it via `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`. I was able to successfully install it without any error but I do receive a new error when I run the script https://pastebin.com/vDSXxmGk

Comment: Looks like `UBA` isn't in your environment variables. Not sure what that is.

Comment: It's the name of my environment. Strange ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that directly with GDAL, which is likely installed if you have QGIS already, both in Python and in the console. Python version here:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gdal

fname = "gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2020_30_sec_portugal"
world = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp"
data = gdal.Warp("", fname, format="MEM", 
                 cutlineDSName=world, cropToCutline=True,
                 dstNodata=-999, 
                 cutlineWhere="NAME='Portugal'"
                ).ReadAsArray()
print(f"Total population {data[data != -999].sum()}")
```

A couple of things:
1. I have cropped to only consider the envelope of Portugal
2. I have set the no data value to -999
3. Your links aren't working anymore, so I just 
    * Downloaded the original dataset (see filename)
    * Used the `TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL` dataset
4. From the `TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL`, I just select the Portugal entry.