# Extract raster value using multipolygon shapefile using python

Tags: python, raster, geopandas, rasterio

I am trying to export raster values using multipolygon shapefile in python. I have found the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260304/extract-raster-values-within-shapefile-with-pygeoprocessing-or-gdal/260380#comment650387_260380), but the calculation there is not valid for multipolygon. Could please someone guide me, how i should correct the code in order to have not polygon but multipolygon datatype in calculation.

My code is below:

````
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from rasterio import Affine
from shapely.geometry import mapping

shapefile = gpd.read_file(r'/Users..../polygon_sector.shp')
geoms = shapefile.geometry.values
geometry = geoms[0] # shapely geometry

# transform to GeJSON format
geoms = [mapping(geoms[0])]
# extract the raster values within the polygon
with rasterio.open("/Users/.../map_reclass.tif") as src:
     out_image, out_transform = mask(src, geoms, crop=True)

# no data values of the original raster
no_data=src.nodata
print(no_data)

# extract the values of the masked array
data = out_image[0,:,:]
# extract the row, columns of the valid values
row, col = np.where(data != no_data)
rou = np.extract(data != no_data, data)

# affine import Affine
T1 = out_transform * Affine.translation(0.5, 0.5)  # reference the pixel centre
rc2xy = lambda r, c: (c, r) * T1

d = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'col':col,'row':row,'ROU':rou})
# coordinate transformation
d['x'] = d.apply(lambda row: rc2xy(row.row,row.col)[0], axis=1)
d['y'] = d.apply(lambda row: rc2xy(row.row,row.col)[1], axis=1)
# geometry
from shapely.geometry import Point
d['geometry'] =d.apply(lambda row: Point(row['x'], row['y']), axis=1)

# save to a shapefile
d.to_file(r'/Users/y.../result_full.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile') ```
````

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, basically going backwards and deleted the part, where i start defining precisely the polygon. As result the code looks the following:

````
import rasterio
from rasterio.mask import mask
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from rasterio import Affine
from shapely.geometry import mapping

shapefile = gpd.read_file(r'/Users..../polygon_sector.shp')
geoms = shapefile.geometry.values

with rasterio.open("/Users/.../map_reclass.tif") as src:
     out_image, out_transform = mask(src, geoms, crop=True)

# no data values of the original raster
no_data=src.nodata
print(no_data)

# extract the values of the masked array
data = out_image[0,:,:]
# extract the row, columns of the valid values
row, col = np.where(data != no_data)
rou = np.extract(data != no_data, data)

# affine import Affine
T1 = out_transform * Affine.translation(0.5, 0.5)  # reference the pixel centre
rc2xy = lambda r, c: (c, r) * T1

d = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'col':col,'row':row,'ROU':rou})
# coordinate transformation
d['x'] = d.apply(lambda row: rc2xy(row.row,row.col)[0], axis=1)
d['y'] = d.apply(lambda row: rc2xy(row.row,row.col)[1], axis=1)
# geometry
from shapely.geometry import Point
d['geometry'] =d.apply(lambda row: Point(row['x'], row['y']), axis=1)

# save to a shapefile
d.to_file(r'/Users/y.../result_full.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile') ```
````