# Clipping Out Many Villages from geotiff image using rasterio?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, clip, rasterio

I have a geo tiff image of a County/State consisting of useful bands data. I have a kml/geojson file consisting of many small territories' boundaries inside this State/County. I would like to clip geotiff Image at all small territories and export it as a tiff. I cant clip each small sub-territory manually as there are around few thousands of them.

How this can be accomplished in rasterio?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any research to figure out how to clip a raster by a polygon in QGIS? Have you done any research to figure out how you can run that as a batch process or write a simple script that does that?

Comment: As much as possible please only ask about one GIS software per question to prevent your questions being too broad

Comment: To focus your question I retrofitted it to your self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using rasterio library as has been described here:[GDAL python cut geotiff image with geojson file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199727/gdal-python-cut-geotiff-image-with-geojson-file?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah well you said you wanted a QGIS solution. You should take a tour to figure out how to ask meaningful questions. https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Please, see my edit @Jon, I clearly mentioned that any software or library would work for me

Comment: Maybe so, but it was not there in your original question.

Comment: "I want to know, how this can be accomplished in QGIS or any other software or library." This line was always there

Comment: I must've overlooked that, sorry.